# How do I use the table header for entries an a row for properties in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

while writing my first JavaFX application I already encountered a problem which I am unfortunately not able to solve myself. I'm trying to change the orientation of a datatable to horizontal, rather than vertical.

The table header should therefore be located on the left hand side while the data records should be displayed in columns rather than rows.
The result should look like this:

[image: desired result]

I'm using scene graph to design my scenes and therefore also fxml. If possible, I'd like to stick to this approach, but if push comes to shove I'd be willing to create the table directly in javacode.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please show some of your code? Just showing an image doesn't reveal that much...

Comment: There's no built-in way to do that with a `TableView`: it is inherently row-based.

Comment: (Or column-based, depending which way you look at it. But you can't reverse the roles of rows and columns.)

Comment: @JonathanLam What do you need a code example for? The table flip should be achieveable with any table, regardless of the example.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the answer. Although it is quite unfortunate - would you post this comment as an answer so I can mark it as solution? If it doesn't work, thats all to it. Guess I have to stick to GridLayouts then :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do what you describe. `TableView`s are not symmetrical: the list of items in the table are always represented as the rows of the table, and column data are represented as mapping from each row object to a property. The header is always a column header.

You might consider [`SpreadsheetView`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) from [ControlsFX](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/), which might give you the functionality you need.